# Single atlas implies global normal coordinates?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, coordinate-systems

Let $M$ be a class $C^k$-Riemannian manifold and suppose there exists an atlas $\langle U,\psi\rangle$ for $M$ containing only one global chart.

- Does this imply that the Riemmanian $Log_p\,(:=Exp_p^{-1})$ maps are
  defined globally?

  Ie: for every point $p\in M$ $Dom(Log_p)=M$?
- If so can we give a simple and explicit description of these coordinates in terms of the map $\psi$?